# Get HTMLInputElement from ref to PrimeReact's InputText

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am trying to use a ref to get to the underlying input element of an InputText component. I used `this.textFieldRef = React.createRef()` to set up the ref, and then the attribute `ref={this.textFieldRef}` to hook it up. Yet in the `componentDidMount` I cannot use `this.textFieldRef.current.select()` because `select()` is not a function available for that object. So somehow, InputText is not returning the underlying HTMLInputElement.

Does anyone know how I can get from a ref to something that allows me to `select()` the text in the InputText element?

Here is my code, which is actually in TypeScript...

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/inputtext';

export class ValueCard extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

  textFieldRef: React.RefObject<any> = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (this.textFieldRef.current instanceof InputText) {
      this.textFieldRef.current.select();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return = (
      <InputText
        value="test"
        ref={this.textFieldRef}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for PrimeReact's `InputText` component ([source](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/blob/master/src/components/inputtext/InputText.js)), they are attaching a reference to the inner `input` element to `this.element`.
This allows you to just add `.element` to your reference:

```
this.textFieldRef.current.element.select();
```

I tested it out in this sandbox, and it seems to work as expect:
https://codesandbox.io/s/203k7vx26j

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use `react-dom` library:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.textFieldRef.current).querySelector('input');
```